PySCF CASSCF wavefunction symmetry not consistent during iteration
I'm tring to use symmetry adapted CASSCF to scan an energy curve of a carbon dimer. Yet with a slightly larger bond length, the SCF iteration always raises a RuntimeError. Here is a sample code:
from pyscf import gto, scf, mcscf
import numpy as np


mol = gto.M(
    atom = """
    C 0 0 0
    C 0 0 1.66
    """, 
    basis = "def2-qzvppd",
    spin = 0,
    charge = 0,
    unit = "angstrom",
    symmetry = True
    )

mf = mol.RHF()
mf.irrep_nelec = { 'A1g': 4, 'A1u': 4, 'E1gx': 2, 'E1gy': 2}
mf.kernel()

mc = mcscf.CASSCF(mf, 10, 8)
mc.verbose = 4
mc.max_cycle_macro = 300
mc.fix_spin_(ss=0.00)
mc.fcisolver.wfnsym = 'A1g'
ncore = { "A1g":1, "A1u":1, }
ncas = { "A1g":3, "A1u":3, "E1gx":1, "E1gy":1, "E1ux":1, "E1uy":1, }
mo = mcscf.sort_mo_by_irrep(mc, mf.mo_coeff, ncas, ncore)
mc.kernel(mo)

The output:
converged SCF energy = -74.6332212035738
ncore for each irreps {'A1g': 1, 'A1u': 1}
ncas for each irreps {'A1g': 3, 'A1u': 3, 'E1gx': 1, 'E1gy': 1, 'E1ux': 1, 'E1uy': 1}
(0-based) caslst = [ 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 18]

******** <class 'pyscf.mcscf.mc1step_symm.SymAdaptedCASSCF'> ********
CAS (4e+4e, 10o), ncore = 2, nvir = 114
max_cycle_macro = 300
max_cycle_micro = 4
conv_tol = 1e-07
conv_tol_grad = None
orbital rotation max_stepsize = 0.02
orbital rotation threshold for CI restart = 0.01
augmented hessian ah_max_cycle = 30
augmented hessian ah_conv_tol = 1e-12
augmented hessian ah_linear dependence = 1e-14
augmented hessian ah_level shift = 1e-08
augmented hessian ah_start_tol = 2.5
augmented hessian ah_start_cycle = 3
augmented hessian ah_grad_trust_region = 3
kf_trust_region = 3
kf_interval = 4
ci_response_space = 4
ci_grad_trust_region = 3
with_dep4 0
natorb = False
canonicalization = True
sorting_mo_energy = False
ao2mo_level = 2
chkfile = /tmp/tmpws_9rhcd
max_memory 4000 MB (current use 431 MB)
internal_rotation = False
******** <class 'pyscf.fci.addons.SpinPenaltyFCISolver'> ********
max. cycles = 50
conv_tol = 1e-08
davidson only = True
linear dependence = 1e-12
level shift = 0.001
max iter space = 12
max_memory 4000 MB
nroots = 1
pspace_size = 400
spin = None
Input CI wfn symmetry = A1g
Symmetries of active orbitals: A1g A1u E1gx E1gy E1uy E1ux A1g A1u A1g A1u
Active space CI wfn symmetry = A1g
CASCI E = -75.4545926073473  S^2 = 0.0000000
Set conv_tol_grad to 0.000316228
macro iter   1 ( 21 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5170185710948  dE = -6.24259637e-02  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|=0.244  |grad[c]|=0.0573  |ddm|=0.118  |maxRot[o]|=0.313
macro iter   2 ( 21 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5400794819329  dE = -2.30609108e-02  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|=0.118  |grad[c]|=0.0226  |ddm|=0.0345  |maxRot[o]|=0.314
macro iter   3 ( 21 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5499509498549  dE = -9.87146792e-03  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|= 0.05  |grad[c]|=0.016  |ddm|=0.0112  |maxRot[o]|=0.275
macro iter   4 ( 21 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5538055301205  dE = -3.85458027e-03  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|=0.0179  |grad[c]|=0.00683  |ddm|=0.016  |maxRot[o]|=0.301
macro iter   5 ( 15 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5543453995065  dE = -5.39869386e-04  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|=0.0197  |grad[c]|=0.00371  |ddm|=0.0232  |maxRot[o]|=0.0635
macro iter   6 ( 15 JK    4 micro), CASSCF E = -75.5545582699970  dE = -2.12870491e-04  S^2 = 0.0000000
               |grad[o]|=0.015  |grad[c]|=0.00211  |ddm|=0.0258  |maxRot[o]|=0.0315
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lexlee/2024-08-U2/test.py", line 29, in <module>
    mc.kernel(mo)
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/mcscf/mc1step_symm.py", line 73, in kernel
    _kern(self, mo_coeff,
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/mcscf/mc1step.py", line 454, in kernel
    e_tot, e_cas, fcivec = casscf.casci(mo, fcivec, eris, log, locals())
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/mcscf/mc1step.py", line 878, in casci
    e_tot, e_cas, fcivec = casci.kernel(fcasci, mo_coeff, ci0, log,
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/mcscf/casci.py", line 608, in kernel
    e_tot, fcivec = casci.fcisolver.kernel(h1eff, eri_cas, ncas, nelecas,
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/fci/direct_spin1_symm.py", line 767, in kernel
    wfnsym_ir = self.guess_wfnsym(norb, nelec, ci0, orbsym, wfnsym, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lexlee/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyscf/fci/direct_spin1_symm.py", line 585, in guess_wfnsym
    raise RuntimeError(f'Input wfnsym {wfnsym} is not consistent with '
RuntimeError: Input wfnsym A1g is not consistent with fcivec symmetry 1

I have read the examples about symmetry adapted CASSCF but I still don't know what should I do to fix that. I really appreciate for the help, thanks!

Seems that the developers have fixed that: https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/pull/2395

Please click "Edit" then click "Community Wiki" and save it.
